# Pannier rack for larger diameter seat post

Tags: seatpost, rack, folding-bicycle, panniers

I have recently purchased an old, second-hand folding (or at least collapsable) bike, a Daewoo shuttle to be precise. In order to use it for commuting, I would like to fit a pannier rack onto it. It has very small wheels (16") and so I was thinking of a seatpost mounted rack, preferably with quick release. Unfortunately, the seatpost diameter is quite large (about 35mm, maybe a touch more) and the one rack I bought (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01DUAMLDA) didn't fit because of the seat post diameter being too large.

I have searched everywhere for a pannier rack that fits large diameter seat posts, but have drawn a blank. Can anybody suggest any pannier rack that would fit or any tips or tricks to make a standard pannier rack fit onto a large diameter seatpost?

Comment: You might have to make something - problem comes if you need to put the seatpost down for folding.

Comment: @Criggie Indeed, that's why I was looking at quick release couplings.

Comment: You might be able to convert to a quick-ish release by replacing the bolts with wing bolts of just the right length.  This would work on a Topeak beam rack, for example (max ⌀31.8 mm so no good to you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably 36 mm; that seems reasonably common. Most seatpost racks go up to 31.8 mm

Taking 36 mm as a guess makes searching much easier: it's an upper limit for some models:

It seems easier to find a trunk bag attachment for such a large post. There is such a thing as a [Rixen & Kaul KLICKfix Caddy Post and Bar Clamp 2016](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/rixen-kaul-klickfix-caddy-post-and-bar-clamp-2016/rp-prod165289?gs=1&sku=sku610907UK&pgrid=50965500405&ptaid=pla-449710967434&utm_source=google&utm_term=&utm_campaign=PLA+All+Products&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mkwid|sTbN5ovGS_dc|pcrid|254166917989|pkw||pmt||prd|610907UK).  That would allow you to mount a handlebar bag on the seatpost, or [this Vaude mount](https://www.bikeshophub.com/product/vaude-offroad-5-trunk-bag-frame-and-seat-post-mounting-kit-p-2065.html) is designed for their trunk bags but could be used with other things.  None of these are of much help if you want to choose a pannier to suit you.

Traditional style racks do exist, such as this [Atran Velo Luggage Carrier Active Seatpost](https://hollandbikeshop.com/en-gb/bicycle-parts-city-bike/luggage-carrier/luggage-carrier-on-seatpost/atran-velo-luggage-carrier-active-seatpost-alu-matt-black/) (which seems to have curved sides, but many panniers would still fit, and it's quick release). The search that turned up that last one (and the Vaude) was `seat post rack "36mm" -rixen`

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. The Atran rack looks promising. What sort of bags are compatible with the Rixen clamp?

Comment: My bar bag is an Altura from about 10 years ago, and uses the same fitting ([here's a review](http://cycleseven.org/altura-dryline-bar-bag-review) but I don't think exactly the same one is made any more).  Altura kit is pretty decent and they have a few to fit.  As the [bag backplate is available as a spare](https://www.evanscycles.com/altura-klickfix-back-plate-EV167270) you could even customise something

Answer (score 1):

I installed on my bicycle Atran Velo Luggage Carrier and this is really a good thing. Definitely recommend.

Comment: Thank you. as Chris H mentioned, the sides of the rack are slightly curved. Does it cause any problem? The spacing between the two clips on my pannier is about 103-104mm.